# unable to invoke applet from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, applet

*applet tag in jsp :*

```
<%--<applet code ="applets/applet_1" height="500" width="500"/>--%>

<jsp:plugin type="applet" code="applet_1.class" codebase="web/WEB-INF/classes/applets"/>

<%--This tag is inside the jsp page which is index.jsp--%>
```

[image]

why don't i see the applet ? I have used Netbeans as the IDE.

*I even tried this !*

[image]

and changed the tag to :

```
<jsp:plugin type="applet" code="applet_1.class" codebase="applets" height="300" width="300"/>
```

but nothing changed .

Comment: @Andrew Thompson why did you remove your answer ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<applet
    name="applet1"
    code="applet_1.class"
    codebase="/web/WEB-INF/classes/applets"
    width="300"
    height="300"

</applet>
```

Comment: i am trying in jsp not in html !

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson in simple words : the answer is incorrect. The value of attribute `codebase` for example

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson because what matters is , does it even take **near** to solving my problem. I don't think it does that. Instead it is incorrect. For example your answer told me a nice thing ,i.e to put the classes in the jars and then utilize them instead of going the wrong way _(web/WEB-INF/..)_. But i still haven't been able to achieve that !